# Character drops through Floor in Game Engine

Tags: game-engine

My character always falls through the ground in my game. I put character physics on it, so it falls, but it always goes through the floor.

I tried to make it land on a skateboard when the game starts, but the skateboard just slips away and they both fall. There is character physics on the skateboard, too. So why does this happen?

[image: right before character drops through ground]

Also, sometimes it won't even fall to the floor and will just shake  and hover above the ground as well as the skateboard. Why will they either fall through or not even touch?

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens when you scale/rotate an object, but don't apply it's scale.

To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>> *Apply scale*.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, firstly, make sure that you also have Collision physics on the plane. The character needs physics, but the plane does, too.

Secondly, your character is intersecting the floor plane. When the physics simulation starts in this kind of situation, it doesn't have any way to decide which side of the plane the character is on, so it freaks out instead.

Re-position your character model so that he's entirely above the plane before the simulation starts.

Vili's suggestion to apply rotation and scale is also a good idea.